# Twilio :making a call

Tags: twilio

I'm not having much luck making a call via Twilio...
I want a button to click while I'm in the office that puts me through to a clients number that I've typed into a web page.

I can do "Click to call": http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call , but that's for the user to phone the company - what I'm after is my company phone phone to call the user.

I thought it would be a simple case of setting the From/To fields in InitiateOutboundCall, and leaving the URL field blank.
It didn't work at all.

I then tried with an empty XML page, because I thought "When the call connects, I don't want the system to do anything else, like saying a message, I just want the two people to talk!

e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Response> </Response>
```

When I do that, the client's phone rings, and it says "Company X" on it, but when the phone is picked up it rings off,

I tried with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>123456</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

And it called the client's phone, then called the staff's phone - but that's the click-to-call I mentioned above.

Please help!

```
Protected sub makeCall()

    Dim options As New CallOptions()

    Dim ACCOUNT_SID = ""
    Dim AUTH_TOKEN = ""
    options.Url = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?

    options.From = "+Number listed in Twilio callers page"
    options.To = "+My mobile number"


    WriteLine(""):WriteLine(""):WriteLine("")

    Dim TwilClient As New TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
    WriteLine("TwilClient created.")

    Dim  outboundCall = TwilClient.InitiateOutboundCall(options)
    WriteLine("Call created.")

    WriteLine("Call status: " & outboundCall.Status)

    If Not IsNothing(outboundCall.RestException )
        WriteLine("ERROR!: " & outboundCall.RestException.Message)
    End If

    IndentLevel +=1
    WriteLine("")
    WriteLine("SID: " & outboundCall.Sid)
    Session("mycallsid") = outboundCall.Sid

    Unindent
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to clarify, do you want to make a phone call right from within the browser?

If that's the case, you'll need to use [Twilio Client](http://www.twilio.com/client), which has a [JavaScript SDK](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js) that you can use to create an audio connection from your browser to Twilio.  Once thats created, you can tell Twilio to connect to a second number and we will bridge the two calls together.

This quickstart shows you how to use Twilio Client with C# to be able to make and receive phone calls from a browser:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client

Hope that helps.

Devin